# How can I add/delete a table row using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking for a simple, effective technique for adding or deleting a row in a html table using JavaScript. (*Without* using jQuery)

Comment: The best way to write such code would be to use an editor :) (and you don't need jQuery for that ;))

Comment: @Felix King  good one dude:-)

Comment: Where is the jQuery aversion based on? You would only end up with 5 times as much as code.

Comment: @BalusC, there are a lot of reasons one wouldn't use jQuery which have nothing to do with an aversion in the sense it seems you mean. Just a few: client requirements, portability, minimal needs for jQuery's feature set (and here, bear in mind that one would have to write at least 120 KB of Javascript to arrive at your "5 times as much code" estimate), dependence on a library which (despite the jQuery team's efforts) conflicts. Just as the answer to every question is not necessarily "use jQuery", the answer to every request for a non-jQuery solution is not "why?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this a month ago...Its not the best way

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>
                Crap work
        </title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_row()
{
        var table = document.getElementById('table');
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);     
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = ' <span onClick="edit(this)">Edit</span>/<span onClick="delete_row(this)">Delete</span>';
        cell3.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.innerHTML = '<span onClick="save(this)">Save</span>';
}


function save(e)
{
    var elTableCells = e.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("td");
    elTableCells[0].innerHTML=elTableCells[0].firstChild.value;
    elTableCells[1].innerHTML=elTableCells[1].firstChild.value;
    elTableCells[2].setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
    elTableCells[3].setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}
function edit(e)
{
    var elTableCells = e.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("td");
    elTableCells[0].innerHTML='<input type="text" value="'+elTableCells[0].innerHTML+'">';
    elTableCells[1].innerHTML='<input type="text" value="'+elTableCells[1].innerHTML+'">';
    elTableCells[2].setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    elTableCells[3].setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
}

function delete_row(e)
{
    e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="display">
    <table id='table'>
        <tr id='id'>
            <td>
                Piemesons
            </td>

            <td>
                    23
            </td>   
            <td >
                <span onClick="edit(this)">Edit</span>/<span onClick="delete_row(this)">Delete</span>
            </td>   
            <td style="display:none;">
                <span onClick="save(this)">Save</span>
            </td>   
        </tr>   
    </table>    
        <input type="button" value="Add new row" onClick="add_row();" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var theTable = document.getElementById("theTable");
theTable.deleteRow(0);  //0 being first row.
```

Comment: YES. It's that simple. While the DOM is far from perfect, it usually isn't that hard.